# enable_if, SFINAE and template parameters?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand `enable_if` and SFINAE.  So far, my use of templates has been explicitly passed template arguments to the template parameters or deduction of template parameters during instantiation.  I'm confused in the code below how the member of enable_if<>::type (typedef int type) can be a template parameter.  I.e. the parameter list becomes `<class T = int, int* = nullptr>`.  I would expect a parameter like this to be `int Z = nullptr`.

Does anyone know what I'm missing in regards to understanding why these template parameters assigned by `enable_if` work?

Thanks

```
 #include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#if 1
template <class T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T& t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
}
#endif

#if 0 // understood
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,
                                 void>::type
do_stuff(T& t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
}
#endif

struct S {};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    do_stuff(i);
    //do_stuff<S>(S{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [cppreference.com entry for enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), shows how the `type` parameter is defined and how it works. After reviewing this reference material, which part of that definition is unclear to you?

Comment: I have been reviewing it for awhile, I'm confused on the syntax / grammar of the template parameter list.  The first example in the code appears to have parameter <class T, int* = nullptr>, the second example from cppreference <class T, class = void>.  My understanding it the template parameter list is composed of types (class, int, etc) and a bound name to that type.  So these examples are confusing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of [template parameters](http://%20https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

- type template parameters
- non-type template parameters

The name of the template parameter is optional

A template parameter can have a default value

## Type template parameter

#### named, non-defaulted

```
template <class T>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<int> x{};
```

#### named, defaulted

```
template <class T = int>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<> x1{};
X<char> x2{};
```

#### unnamed non-defaulted

```
template <class>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<int> x{};
```

#### unnamed, defaulted

```
template <class = int>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<> x1{};
X<char> x2{};
```

## Non-type template parameter

#### named, non-defaulted

```
template <int I>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<24> x{};
```

#### named, defaulted

```
template <int I = 24>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<> x1{};
X<11> x2{};
```

#### unnamed, non-defaulted

```
template <int>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<11> x{};
```

#### unnamed, defaulted

```
template <int = 24>
struct X {};
```

Usage:

```
X<> x1{};
X<11> x2{};
```

---

For SFINAE the technique requires a default value. Since you don't care for the parameter inside the class you can skip its name. As for the type or non-type you can chose which one is easier to write in your particular case.

Comment: So in my case I have a non-type, unnamed defaulted parameter? <class T, int* = nullptr> ?

Comment: @notaorb exactly

Comment: My confusion is that `int*` is unnamed and I haven't had to make an assignment operation to an unnamed value.  It's like assigning directly to the type, which is typically named.  So I guess there must be some implicit name for the unnamed type `int*` that takes the assignment...

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is anonymous. The type and default is specified, but there's nothing to actually refer to it later.

```
template<typename> struct A; // fine
template<int> struct B; // fine
template<typename F, F = nullptr> struct C; // fine
using AI = A<int>;
using BI = B<5>;
using CI = C<int, 5>;
using CD = C<void*>; // all fine
using Oops = C<char>; // not fine
```

Your case just replaces the simpler types like `int` and `F` with a big honking `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`. We don't care about the actual argument that gets passed it ends up being, so that's why it's unnamed.

```
template <class T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T &t) {
    std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
}
```

Plugging in `T = int`, `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type = void`, so the second defaulted parameter just looks like `void* = nullptr`, which means it's an unnamed parameter of type `void*` that defaults to `nullptr`. Note that the `typename` is part of the type of a non-type template parameter. It is not serving in its other capacity as the introducer of type template parameters. Also, please note that the modern C++ way to write this is

```
// typename instead of class is more a style thing
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
```

where `enable_if_t` and `is_integral_v` are aliases that abbreviate all the `::value` and `typename ...::type` nonsense:

```
namespace std {
    template<typename T>
    constexpr inline bool is_integral_v = std::is_integral<T>::value;
    template<bool B, typename T = void>
    using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;
}
```